# Solving equations with SymPy in Python

Tags: python, sympy

Beginner programmer here. Been given a task of using python to figure out when an account containing 10000$ earning 0,5% monthly interest and having 500$ withdrawn every month is empty. I've tried to use SymPy to create an equation to solve the problem, but I keep getting a NotImplementedError.

This is the code I've tried to use:
import sympy

```
x = symbols('x')
Interest_periods = 1.005**x
Accumulated_expenses = 500*x
Balance = (10000*Interest_periods-Accumulated_expenses)
Months_until_depleted = solve(Balance, x)
print(Months_until_depleted)
```

Any tips? Grateful for any help

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error (i.e., "No algorithms are implemented to solve equation 10000*(201/200)**x - 500*x") because *solutions cannot be represented symbolically*. For example, the equation x = cos(x) has a solution, but it cannot be represented symbolically using standard functions.

In fact, `solve` makes no guarantees whatsoever about the completeness of the solutions it finds. Much of solve is heuristics, which may find some solutions to an equation or system of equations, but not all of them.

So your code is not wrong, but you're trying to get a symbolic solution that simply can't be found (not even if you try by hand).